# Adjustable regenerative braking

Tags: motor, power-electronics, regenerative

In electric cars, one way to brake is to turn the motor into a generator, extracting energy from the motor, and slowing the car down. I'm not sure, but my guess for how to decrease and increase the braking force would be to change the load on the motor, causing faster changes in current, leading to more flux due to the changing magnetic field.

How is the load on the motor actively changed though, to provide a variable braking force?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The electronics used in modern cars provide excellent control of braking.

A simplistic explanation: permanent magnet motors always generate a voltage when they are spinning. This is called back EMF. In order to make them spin faster you need to supply a voltage higher than the back EMF so current flows into the motor. In order to brake, you need to apply a voltage lower than the back EMF, so current flows from the motor into the controller. The lower the voltage the more the braking. So the controller just needs to manage this process to achieve the desired effect. The technique used to vary the voltage is PWM switching of MOSFETs or IGBTs (this is very similar to DC-DC converters such as the buck or boost converter).

This is equally true for brushed DC motors, brushless DC motors (BLDCs), and Permanent Magnet Synchronous Motors (PMSMs). But for BLDCs and PMSMs, the voltage is an AC wave rather than a DC voltage. So there is the additional important detail of synchronizing the AC wave to the motor speed.

And there is one more detail which is that the voltage needs to be phase shifted just a bit to compensate for motor inductance. So in addition to synchronization, the AC needs to peak a bit earlier the faster the motor spins.

Field oriented control deals with all of this. You may wish to type "field oriented control of PMSMs" into your favorite search engine.

Once you get into it you find lots of additional details. This is just a very brief conceptual overview.

Comment: Applying the voltage lower than the back EMF means extracting power from the motor, which is furnished (before losses) by the motion of the car (kinetic energy) causing the wheels to turn and force the motor to spin.  Ideally, all of this extracted power would be channeled into removing the load from or charging the battery.

Comment: @Technophile yes, when using the motor as a generator, you would ideally like to channel the energy into the battery. UNLESS the battery is already full OR the rate of energy production is so fast that it would result in excessive charge current for the battery.

Comment: Which raises the question:  when braking begins abruptly, I suppose the battery system must simply be designed to (1) be able to accept the maximum braking current, and/or (2) have something it can do with the excess electrical power, should the batteries be fully charged and e.g. the vehicle be descending a long hill.  Or is that something the backup mechanical brakes cover?

Comment: @technophile, one must consider that scenario, yes. I think (but I am not 100 percent sure) that automobiles automatically apply mechanical brakes as needed so the driver doesn't have to think about it. I worked on an electric skateboard, and we opted to put a braking resistor in the deck of the board (on the bottom). So if the battery was full or the charge rate was too high for the batteries, we would dump excess current into the resistor. On some e-bikes, I believe that regen is triggered by a separate button or something, and they still have normal mechanical brakes.

Comment: Perhaps (for automotive) the "full" battery charge level is adjusted by altitude, proximity to long downhill roads, the location of the charger, other factors, and / or the manufacturer simply leaves a margin -- "full" charge is not precise.  Charging above a nominal 100% charge is possible, at the cost of reduced battery life, if of long duration.  Getting fancier, chargers at the peak of a pass might be set to stop charging earlier (or based on information from the vehicle), leaving extra margin for downhill regenerative braking.